# Can you use C++ with the macOS SDK?

Tags: c++, swift, macos

I want to write an application targeting both macOS and Linux computers. I would like to write my application in C++ instead of Swift. Am I able to use macOS's SDK/API (i.e. use things like this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lapolicy) in C++? I can't find any C++ libraries allowing me to do things like access fingerprint authentication on macOS, and Apple's docs only show API usage in Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: You can, but you'll have to write a *ton* of C++ to Swift bridge code. Maybe you can find a project where someone's already done this.

Comment: Which APIs are you wanting to use specifically? Apple's own higher-level APIs are best consumed by Objective-C or Swift - the bindings for other languages are pretty gnarly. The lower-level and BSD APIs are all POSIX C-style though, however.

Comment: As an aside, this is why [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org) exists, and also that Swift is cross-platform, so ironically writing in Swift for Linux might be easier as Swift can make C calls more easily than C++ can make Swift calls.

Comment: I would like to create an application where users can take advantage of the Touch ID fingerprint reader on newer MacBooks to decrypt their information. There's information on how to do this in Swift/ObjC on Apple's docs but nothing for other languages, unfortunately.

Comment: That's because Apple dropped support for those languages years back. If you want to use C++ you must write or use a C++ to Swift adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. In that case I will look into using Swift instead.

Answer (score 1):

The short demo below further demonstrates that C++ and objc may be mixed.  In this example a C++ class contains objc code.  To run in Xcode delete the contents of the main.m file in an Xcode objc project and replace it with the following.  Then change the extension of the main.m file to .mm and hit run.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

NSTextView *txtView;

//prints formatted NSString with line feed
void NSLog(NSString *formatString, ... ) {
va_list ap;
va_start( ap, formatString );
NSString *format = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@\n", formatString] ;
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:ap];
[txtView insertText:str replacementRange:NSMakeRange( [[txtView string] length], 0 )];
va_end( ap );
}

class Window {
public:
 void buildWnd();
 void printContent();
private:
 NSWindow *window;
};

void Window::buildWnd() {
    
#define _wndW  600
#define _wndH  550
window = [ [ NSWindow alloc ] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW, _wndH )
    styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskTitled
    backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
[window center];
[window setTitle: @"Test window" ];
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    
// **** NSTextView **** //
txtView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,60,_wndW,_wndH-60)];
[txtView setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Lucida Grande" size:14]];
[[window contentView]addSubview:txtView];
NSLog(@"Kilroy was here.");

// **** Quit btn **** //
 NSButton *quitBtn = [[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( _wndW - 60, 10, 40, 40 )];
 [quitBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleCircular ];
 [quitBtn setTitle: @"Q" ];
 [quitBtn setAction:@selector(terminate:)];
 [[window contentView] addSubview: quitBtn];
}

void Window::printContent(){
 NSLog(@"Hello world!!");
 NSLog(@"window = %@", window);
}

int main () {
 [NSApplication sharedApplication];
 Window w;
 w.buildWnd();
 w.printContent();
 [NSApp run];
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compile your C++ code for macOS, but native macOS APIs (like fingerprint authentication you mentioned) are only available in ObjC/Swift languages.

To access native macOS APIs, you can add macOS specific portion of code (written in ObjC or Swift) to your cross-platform C++ code. You can use [Scapix](https://github.com/scapix-com/scapix) to automatically generate C++ binding for ObjC and Swift (among other languages).

Disclaimer: I am the author of [Scapix Language Bridge](https://github.com/scapix-com/scapix).

Comment: A small question: I'd assume calling private functions as extern in C++ should mean no problems right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use OC and C++ mixed editing, just modify the .m file to .mm suffix
you can see here:[OC and C++ mixed](https://www.jianshu.com/p/fe9b6091998f)